# Application Insights live metrics not working with 2.4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I'm having issues getting live metrics to work on a MVC 5 web app.I've tried a number of projects including web api 2 and I get the same issue where it says the server is offline or I'm using an older version of the SDK.  To add to the weirdness it seems to be specific to my work pc. I took a web api project from my work machine and tried it at home and it worked out the box. Now I'm not sure if its a permissions issue on my work account or a firewall issue. I've tried to rule out the firewall issue by using my laptop at home but I still get the same issue. Any suggestions of wheat I can try next

Comment: This sounds like some proxy issue at work. Can you capture traffic from your web project using Fiddler and see what's happening with Live Metrics requests (they are issued every 5 seconds)?

Comment: There was nothing unusual in fidler. I'm going to check with our network team to see if something is blocking it in the proxy